# Unix time stamp to date

Tags: views

I'm displaying a custom table in a view with Data & Schema module.
One of my field in that table is created_date, int of unix timestamp.
The view's page shown as table, how can I display it in a readble format?

Answer (score 4):

You need to describe the table for views to know which handler to use. For that you have to implement [hook_views_data_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data_alter/7). It looks complicated at first, but its definitely worth it :).

EDIT :
Data & Schema should allow you to set the handler, somewhere in the properties of the table. I haven't used it for a while but am quite sure its there :).

Answer (score 2):

Normally you define the handler type in `hook_views_data`

The Data module presumably allows something similar

e.g:

```
  // Expose the created and changed timestamps.
  $data['my_table']['created'] = array(
    'title' => t('Created date'),
    'help' => t('The date the record was created.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_date',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort_date',
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_date',
    ),
  );
```

Note the "_date" type handlers there. That's all Views needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own custom date in the Date Format Settings:

1. Navigate to /admin/config/regional/date-time.
2. Click on "Formats" tab.
3. Click "Add Format".
4. Add a single "U" character to the text field.  Using [PHP's Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) syntax this is Unix timestamp.
5. Save, and go back to Types.
6. Add Date Type.
7. Call it whatever you want.  I recommend "Unix Time", attach your format to it.  (Will display something like "1427999400".
8. Save and go back to your View.  Format your date as "Unix Timestamp" wherever you need to, without mucking with nasty template files or hacking around to make simple changes.

Comment: I believe this is the opposite of what is required. the OP wanted to go from unixt time to a date not the other way around

Comment: Yeah, I mean it's been a few years since I answered this but if I remember correctly the problem is that the date isn't stored in the database correctly.  When you format your date as "Unix Timestamp" it's telling the backend that your date is being stored as a timestamp.  Then your views or formatters can appropriately format the date as you want for any field, even in different formats for different views, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Install [views_php module](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) module,
add your field and exclude form display,
add another field ,global php field
in output  write someting like below

```
<?php   print format_date($rown->timestamp); ?>
```

for more details read [format_date api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_date/7)

Comment: It's not inside the module. This is a View -> Page

Comment: Using PHP fields in views is highly discouraged. There are performance and security considerations. It is best to define a hook_views_data_alter for the field. There are numerous examples available.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is by formatting the date in a views field template. The ideal way to do it is as @mojzis mentions.

To do it in a views field template:

1. Include the field in the view as normal.
2. In the view go to Advanced > Theme: Information and find the field you need, copy the last template suggestion, something like views-view-field-date--view-name--view-display-id--view-node.tpl.php
3. Copy the file from modules/views/theme/views-view-field.tpl.php to your theme directory and rename it to the name from step 2.
4. Edit this file to be  using the date format you require.

I believe that should do it, the only problem might be that $output isn't the raw timestamp, in that case you should be able to manipulate it before outputting.

I know it's not 'pure' to do this at the theme level, but it's arguably related to content display rather than functionality.